# Why are votes locked in?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes, up-votes, votes

Sometimes people misread a question or answer, or sometimes discussion in comments or edits in other places will clarify something and cause a shift in perspective that will make a person change their mind about a previously cast vote.

However, it isn't possible to change because votes are locked in unless that specific question or answer is edited.  It may be that no edit is necessary or even desired, yet the vote sticks...

I can't think of a compelling reason for forcing such a commitment, and this rule would seem to be at odds with continuous improvement. So, why is it this way?  Who can decide to change it?

Comment: I *think* that is a Stack Exchange policy; I'll see if I can find something in SE Meta that explains it.  I'm not aware of any per-site setting on this (though I could be mistaken).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a safeguard against certain types of abuse, as explained in the answers to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75477/312025) and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80762/312025). You aren't alone in seeing this as a nuisance to those who aren't trying to abuse the voting system and have legit reasons for changing their mind about a question (i.e. 128 upvotes for a comment on one of those meta threads decrying this "feature").

But it is a Stack Exchange deal, not at all specific to Aviation, and it seems to be in the category of "it's been discussed, and it is what it it."

The work-around (which you have the rep to do) is to make a trivial edit to the question, fix your vote, and then roll back the edit.  Of course, that may bump the question on the active list, so it's not an ideal solution.